# Can you use the paired t-test in what seems like an unpaired t-test situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value

I came across a situation where a large retailer is testing a new retail program.  It selected specific pilot retail stores to test this program.  Next, it selected a control group of retail stores so that it would be as similar as possible as the pilot retail stores.  It matched each pilot store to one control store based on numerous sociodemographic and business metrics.  The selection criteria was to generate a P value from a student t test as high as possible, indicating a good match between two stores.  This all made good sense.  On the other hand, they told me they used the paired t test.  This was a surprise.  I thought this would be a classic unpaired t test situation.

Comment: The use of matching followed by a paired t-test is fine; there's some point to that (to control for other variables). The matching makes it paired. However, the way it was done -- the use of *the p-value of the test itself* as the matching criterion -- renders the resulting p-value meaningless. It's certainly no longer uniformly distributed under the null. The hypothesis test is effectively useless.

Comment: It sounds to me like there were two sets of paired t-tests that produced p-values. The first set was to make sure the covariates used for matching were balanced across treatment and control groups. You can imagine testing square footage, percentage affluent in trade area, and maybe pre-treatment outcomes, and so on in this way. The second test was a t-test on the equality of post-treatment outcome (like profits and revenue). Was that the case?

Comment: @Glen_b why not make that into an answer? It seems like one to me

Comment: It would have been better to select the pairs before selecting which one of each pair was to be the pilot and which the control.

Comment: @PeterFlom It may have been better to wait for the OP to clarify in response to Dimitriy's comment, but I have done as you suggested (while adding the appropriate caveats that relate to that comment).

Comment: I do not understand the question because how the unpaired t-test was "used" is not apparent.  Could you clarify?  In particular, I am interested in whether you are asking solely about the method of matching treatment to control stores, or whether you are asking about how the treatment and control stores were eventually compared.

Comment: Sorry, not to respond on a more timely basis.  I have had no access to this site for 24 hours.  The paired t test was indeed used twice.  The first time was pre-treatment.  And, in this situation the objective was to maximize the similarity based on various sociodemographic and business indicators between the Pilot and Control Stores.  In this situation, you wanted to get a P value as high as possible suggesting very little difference between the stores.  There was a second paired t test conducted after the "treatment."  My main concern was the use of the paired t test in those situations.

Comment: @GaetanLion, I didn't follow this thread attentively, but... If you want to optimally pair-match two samples, no statistical testing is needed. There is a number of _algorithms for matching_. For example "fuzzy matching" or famous "hungarian algorithm".

Answer (score 5):

The use of matching on other characteristics than that being tested, followed by a paired t-test is fine; there's a point to that (to control for the effect of other variables thought to be relevant to the outcome).

The matching makes it paired, because - if the characteristics on which the matching was carried out* affect the outcome - the pair-members will tend to be more alike than two random observations.

* or other characteristics which are related to them.

See, for example, the discussion in the third paragraph ('*A paired samples t-test based on a "matched-pairs sample"*...') [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples).

Henry's point that the pairs should be selected before deciding on which is to be the pilot (randomly) is a good one, though that problem won't necessarily invalidate the test - depending, for example, on how those pilots were chosen.

However, unless Dimitriy's supposition was correct - that two lots of tests were done, one on the matching variables, and then a different test later for the effect of interest - then the way the matching was done, using the p-value of the test of interest as the matching criterion, renders the resulting p-value meaningless. It's certainly no longer uniformly distributed under the null. In that case, the hypothesis test is effectively useless as it stands.

Comment: Sorry, not to respond on a more timely basis. I have had no access to this site for 24 hours. The paired t test was indeed used twice. The first time was pre-treatment. And, in this situation the objective was to maximize the similarity based on various sociodemographic and business indicators between the Pilot and Control Stores. In this situation, you wanted to get a P value as high as possible suggesting very little difference between the stores. There was a second paired t test conducted after the "treatment." My main concern was the use of the paired t test in those situations.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why "using the p-value as the matching criterion, renders the resulting p-value meaningless."  That's the one information you derive from any student t test.  If you are not going to use its p value, you are essentially not using the test.  Here the objective was to render the Pilot and Control groups as similar to each other before the treatment.  Thus, looking for a p-value as close to 1 made good sense.

Comment: Whoever just downvoted this answer: it would be very useful to know what part of the answer is wrong so it can be corrected.

Comment: I did based on my comments of October 7th.  Maybe I misunderstood your comment.  And, if you can clarify it I may reverse the direction of my vote.

Comment: @GaetanLion thanks for responding; at least I understand why there's suddenly a downvote, so that improves your chances of a relevant response. I'll try to clarify further shortly.